# Image processing - face wrinkles removal algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing, face-detection

everyone

I am currently doing a project in which i am trying to modify a picture of face such that the wrinkles on the face will be removed. Has anyone any clue how to do that? Any algorithm?

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: You're doing a project out of the blue ? with no theory or anything concrete behind it ? ... You know there's **MATH** concerned, right ?

Comment: I definitely know that there is a lot of math behind it. I am in search of some algorithm for this purpose. I have been reading skinning algorithms as I thought I will have to take this face as an object to which i will have to apply skinning. So the wrinkles would automatically be removed. Am I going in right direction? Kindly guide.

Comment: Skinning seems to imply a 3D-model while a picture is 2D. If so, then no, you are not heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to select the wrinkles "automagically" (using a GUI), you may want to look at inpainting, and also at "Poisson Image Editing", by Perez et al. (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.6932&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
This latter technique is also known as "Gradient blending."

I tried to remove one wrinkle (it is positioned at 7 o'clock) using Poisson editing. Left: Before; Right: After:

[image]

The code is in Mathematica, and is too "mispackaged" to be really useful.

As for inpainting, the texture synthesis technique gives this:

```
Inpaint[eye, w, Method -> "TextureSynthesis"]
```

[image]